# How to grab a cell value and write it as a new column. Excel to SQL copy activity Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have a copy activity pipeline that simply copies cells A6:C9 into sql table.
[image]

[image]

However, now I need to grab the value in a cell A3 (date) and write it as a new column in sql table.

[image]

How can I achieve that?
Do I need to use another copy activity? Or it can be done in a single one?

UPDATE: value A3:A3 in Lookup activity.

[image]

Comment: Could you share 1) error screenshot and 2)screenshot of lookup activity dataset preview data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fetch the desired value with a Lookup activity, and then add it to the Copy Data activity as an additional column. Please see the example below.

Start by creating a range parameter on your Excel dataset, so you may provide it dynamically in the pipeline:

[image: Parameterizing Excel dataset]

Make sure the Range parameter is added in the Connection tab as well.

[image]

Next, create a pipeline with a Lookup activity, followed by a Copy Data activity. The lookup activity should provide the range for the cell you want to capture (in my case, B1)

[image: Lookup activity]

Finally, in the Copy Data activity, insert an additional column and provide it the Lookup activity output.

[image: Copy Data activity]

The expression I used is `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_0`. This will add a column called Date with the value in B1, for every row.

Comment: Thanks. Getting an error while debuging: `The expression 'activity('dateValue').output.firstRow.Prop_0' cannot be evaluated because property 'firstRow' doesn't exist, available properties are 'effectiveIntegrationRuntime, billingReference, durationInQueue'.`

Comment: I tried to uncheck `"First Row Only"` property but that did not help

Comment: Hi @Serdia, this error indicates the Lookup activity did not find the value (likely hit an empty cell). In your case, it should be pointed at A3:A3. I've also added a screenshot for the dataset configuration, in case that helps.

Comment: I did set value to A3:A3 in Lookup , exactly where date field in my Excel sheet (see snip). However, it still gives me that error.

Comment: I think I figured, In my dataset I unchecked "First row as header" and now it works. Thank you